# SQL find value between borders

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a coordinate consisting of `lat,lon` I want to find the dataset where the value is between the borders `(lat1, lat2)` and `(lon1, lon2)`.

Here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kjqBBbytruoCGBHp6qXhKa/0) I've created to solve this problem, however I'm wondering if there is no builtin function for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on MySQL 5.7 or above, you may wanna take a look at [Spatial Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html).

More specifically, [MBRContains()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrcontains):

> **MBRContains(g1, g2)**
>
> Returns `1` or `0` to indicate whether the minimum bounding rectangle of
> `g1` contains the minimum bounding rectangle of `g2`.

```
mysql> SET @g1 = ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))');
mysql> SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('Point(1 1)');
mysql> SELECT MBRContains(@g1,@g2), MBRWithin(@g2,@g1);
+----------------------+--------------------+
| MBRContains(@g1,@g2) | MBRWithin(@g2,@g1) |
+----------------------+--------------------+
|                    1 |                  1 |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

To cover your specific need what you might do is something like:

```
SELECT name
FROM test.FOO
WHERE MBRContains(
    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("Polygon((", lat1, " ", lon1, ",", lat2, " ", lon1, ",", lat2, " ", lon2, ",", lat1, " ", lon2, ",", lat1, " ", lon1,"))")),
    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("Point(", 1.2, " ", 0.2, ")"))
) = 1;
```

There might be a less messy function to make `Polygon`s and `Point`s, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay, so this is the function, but how can I return the `name` from my dataset? Like `NRW` or `Hessen`

Comment: SELECT name
WHERE MBRContains(<polygon from lat/lon/1/2 coordinates>, <point from your input>) = 1

Comment: @0x45 see example, might need some tweaking.

Comment: Nice! That's what I was searching for, however if you would update your last function I can accept it, it currently has syntax errors. Here is the actual correct syntax: 
`SELECT name
FROM test.FOO
WHERE MBRContains(
  ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("Polygon((
                         ", lat1, " ", lon1, ","
                         , lat2, " ", lon1, ","
                         , lat2, " ", lon2, ","
                         , lat1, " ", lon2, ","
                         , lat1, " ", lon1,
                         "))")),
  ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("Point(", 1.2, " ", 0.2, ")"))) = 1;
`